# Cannot render SSRS report when deployed to different IIS website

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS reports on my job, so really sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'll happily give you all info you need.

The reports are rendered using ASP.NET. When I run the website locally, everything works fine. However when I publish my website to `C:/blablabla`, it throws an error saying:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException: An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) --->     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException: Cannot create a connection to data source 'TPLite'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) ---> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException: Login failed for user 'DESKSOLUTIONS\DESK-RD-04$'.
--- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
--- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
bij Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
bij Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
bij Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode PaginationMode, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
bij Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
bij Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Report.Render(String format)
bij SociopackWS.Datalogic.S2020Mgr.MaakStocklijst() in C:\Users\avanhoutte\Documents\Projects\Sociopack Webservice\SociopackWS\SociopackWS\Datalogic\S2020MGR.cs:regel 849
```

After a bit of debugging I noticed this is the line where it fails:

```
var bytes = rptViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
```

The error says something about a data source TPLite, which is used in the report itself. The datasource gets the connectionstring from a parameter, which is in both scenario's passed along.

Comment: Is logging in to the TPLite datasource with user DESKSOLUTIONS\DESK-RD-04$ the thing you are trying to do? First thing to check is that this login can see that data source in that location.

Comment: Are you able to get into your SSRS Admin (web site)?

Comment: The parameter that I pass to the datasource is just the connectionstring which is `Data Source=DESK-RD-04;Initial Catalog=BMZ;User Id=sa;Password=sa;`. And by SSRS Admin site do you mean `DESK-RD-04/reports`? because yes I can acces that